# Eliminate black border around nodata/alpha of GeoTIFF converted by rasterio

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, mapnik

I have an image (`png`) that I want to place on a map:

[image]

I use [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/georeferencing.html) to georeference the picture:

```py
import rasterio as rio
import warnings
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Tuple
from rasterio.transform import from_bounds

Bbox = Tuple[float, float, float, float]

def georeference_raster(
        raster_in: Path, bbox: Bbox, crs_out: str,
        raster_out: Path = None, height_offset: int = None, 
        width_offset: int = None, width_mod: int = None, 
        height_mod: int = None):
    """
    Convert regular png/tif to georeferenced 
    raster by applying bounds to the image.
    """
    if raster_out is None:
        raster_out = raster_in 
    if width_offset is None:
        width_offset = 0
    if height_offset is None:
        height_offset = 0
    if width_mod is None:
        width_mod = 0
    if height_mod is None:
        height_mod = 0
    bands = [1, 2, 3]
    west, south, east, north = bbox
    with rio.open(raster_in, 'r') as ds:
        data = ds.read(bands)
        transform = from_bounds(
            west-width_offset, south-height_offset, 
            east+width_offset, north+height_offset, 
            ds.width+width_mod, ds.height+height_mod)
    
    with rio.open(
            raster_out, 'w', driver='GTiff',
            width=ds.width, height=ds.height,
            count=3, dtype=data.dtype, nodata=0,
            transform=transform, crs=crs_out) as dst:
        dst.write(data, indexes=bands)
```

This will convert the `png` to a `tif`. However, the `nodata` is stored as black:

[image: [![enter image description here][2]][2]{ width=50% }]

If I use `data = ds.read(bands, fill_value=255)` and `nodata=255`, the image is stored with white background, but the black borders remain:

[image]

Both options will result in slight black edges rendered around the image during overlay (e.g. in Mapnik):

[image]

Is there a way to avoid this?

[edit]

I avoided my issue with the following workaround:
Instead of removing the background with [rembg](https://github.com/danielgatis/rembg), I left the white background in the image and used `comp-op="multiply"` in the Mapnik stylesheet. The white disappears in this case and the map looks like this, without black border artifact:

[image]

Comment: How can it convert a png into tif when using `raster_out, 'w', driver='png'`? Where is the alpha, if band count=3?

Comment: You're right, this was a leftover from testing. I updated my question above. The results for `driver='GTiff'` are nonetheless the same.

Comment: Is this also a leftover `This will convert the png to a tif, with the alpha mask.` You have defined nodata=0 (black) and 3 bands, so the resulting TIFF with those settings will not have alpha. I suggest to open your image with QGIS over some background layer. If you do not see black borders then the issue is in Mapnik. Can you share the original png?

Comment: I opened the image in Irfanview (see the third image above), and I do see the black artifact border. There is no difference if I add `nodata=0` on `ds.read()` or not.

Comment: So I believe that the issue is somehow present already in the source image. Maybe it has an inaccurate mask or something.

Comment: Yes, this was my feeling, too. The image was prepared with `rembg`, which removes the background. However, I found that leaving the white background in the image and using `comp-op="multiply"` in Mapnik solves the issue - there is no need for an alpha mask in this case. I'll still leave the question open, as I have found others with the same issue.